# How to convert a game written for PC to android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have finished a game written in C# using Unity3d which works on PC consoles. Unity3d lets me choose which platform I wish to build it on and one of the option is Android.

What I don't get is, my current controls is W A S D for the main character. When it comes to phones, I am going to need motions such as swipes and clicks so the interface doesn't match.

So when I build it on Android using the option in Unity3d, am I getting some kind of automatic conversion(highly doubt it) or do I need to rewrite the entire source code using Android/ Java and its API.

I am new to this. Thanks for help.

Comment: If you are using the `Input` classes, you should be using methods on this class to read cues from the input system. The input manager and input class abstract input commands away from the device itself so you can concentrate on commands and their meaning rather than what device is being used. As long as you write code to interpret the input and map it to the commands you are good to go. It does depend on your game, but most of the time you can do stuff like adding an on-screen pad which etc to deal with touch interfaces. Info: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, there is no magic genie. There's going to be some work on your side if you plan on porting your game to Android. To give you and idea of what to expect, you have to realize that mobile devices are nothing like desktop devices. You're going to be working under a new set of rules(performance wise, and design wise), so it's likely that you are going to need to fine-tune certain parts of your game to support the Android Mobile Device.

Take a look at Unity's Documentation on [Getting Started With Android Development](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html).

More specifically, pay heed to the "How Unity Android Differs from Desktop Unity" section of the documentation I have linked above. There are quite a few caveats. ;)

In terms of handling gestures and input on Android Devices take a look at: [Android Scripting in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-API.html)